# Cordova ios disable horizontal wipe

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using the latest version of `cordova` `5.4.0` on `iOS` and I want to disable horizontal [wipes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B5Nb.png).

Comment: Have you already tried something ?

Comment: Are you using `ionic`, `jquery` or anything else?